# BeforeMiddleware implementation requires core::ops::Fn implementation

Tags: rust, web-frameworks, iron

I am trying to implement the `BeforeMiddleware` trait for a `struct` I have. I have written the following code:

```
impl BeforeMiddleware for Auth {
    fn before(&self, _: &mut Request) -> IronResult<()> {
        println!("before called");
        Ok(())
    }

    fn catch(&self, _: &mut Request, err: IronError) -> IronResult<()> {
        println!("catch called");
        Err(err)
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
> cargo build
...
src/handlers/mod.rs:38:11: 38:28 error: the trait `for<'r, 'r, 'r> core::ops::Fn<(&'r mut iron::request::Request<'r, 'r>,)>` is not implemented for the type `auth::Auth` [E0277]
src/handlers/mod.rs:38     chain.link_before(auth);
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/handlers/mod.rs:38:11: 38:28 help: run `rustc --explain E0277` to see a detailed explanation
src/handlers/mod.rs:38:11: 38:28 error: the trait `for<'r, 'r, 'r> core::ops::FnOnce<(&'r mut iron::request::Request<'r, 'r>,)>` is not implemented for the type `auth::Auth` [E0277]
src/handlers/mod.rs:38     chain.link_before(auth);
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/handlers/mod.rs:38:11: 38:28 help: run `rustc --explain E0277` to see a detailed explanation
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
...
```

But [the documentation](http://ironframework.io/doc/iron/middleware/struct.Chain.html#method.link_before) says the `link_before` function requires a `BeforeMiddleware` only.

Does anyone know why I am seeing this error and how to fix it?

EDIT:

I was actually using a static `auth`, after making it non-static the problem went away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works just fine:

```
extern crate iron;

use iron::{Chain, BeforeMiddleware, IronResult, Request, Response, IronError};
use iron::status;

struct Auth;

impl BeforeMiddleware for Auth {
    fn before(&self, _: &mut Request) -> IronResult<()> {
        println!("before called");
        Ok(())
    }

    fn catch(&self, _: &mut Request, err: IronError) -> IronResult<()> {
        println!("catch called");
        Err(err)
    }
}

fn main() {
    fn hello_world(_: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
        Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, "Hello World!")))
    }

    let mut c = Chain::new(hello_world);
    let auth = Auth;
    c.link_before(auth);
}
```

This compiles against iron 0.2.6.

Comment: The code I put in the question is not exactly what I was using, the only difference was `auth` was static. After making it non-static it just worked. Thanks.