# Cannot create an Iron handler because the trait bound std::ops::Fn<(&mut iron::Request)> is not satisfied

Tags: rust, iron

I'm trying to create a handler for Iron requests:

```
extern crate iron;
extern crate mount;

use iron::{Iron, Request, Response, IronResult, status};
use mount::Mount;
use iron::middleware::Handler;

struct Server {
    message: String
}

impl Server {
    pub fn start(&self){
        let mut mount = Mount::new();
        mount.mount("/", &self);
        Iron::new(mount).http("0.0.0.0:3000").unwrap();
    }
}

impl Handler for Server {
    fn handle(&self, _req: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response>{
        Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, self.message)))
    }
}

fn main() {
    Server{message: "test".to_string()}.start();
}
```

but compiler response is:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'r, 'r, 'r> Server: std::ops::Fn<(&'r mut iron::Request<'r, 'r>,)>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:15:15
   |
15 |         mount.mount("/", &self);
   |               ^^^^^ trait `for<'r, 'r, 'r> Server: std::ops::Fn<(&'r mut iron::Request<'r, 'r>,)>` not satisfied
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::ops::FnOnce<(&mut iron::Request<'_, '_>,)>` for `&Server`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `iron::Handler` for `&&Server`
```

I was unable to understand what Rust is saying to me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34489422 has the same error

Comment: As does http://stackoverflow.com/q/38659008

Comment: You should upgrade to the newest version of Rust, which has improved error messages and error message formatting. I've updated your error message to the newer format because it's easier for us to read here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a reproduction of your issue; can you spot the problem?

```
trait Foo {}

struct Bar;

impl Foo for Bar {}

impl Bar {
    fn thing(&self) {
        requires_bar(self);
    }
}

fn requires_bar<F>(foo: F) where F: Foo {}

fn main() {}
```

Give up?

You've implemented the trait for your struct:

```
impl Handler for Server
```

But are then trying to use **a reference to a reference to your struct**, which does *not* implement the trait:

```
pub fn start(&self) {
    // ...
    mount.mount("/", &self);
    // ...
}
```

So that cannot work. You need to restructure your code or implement the trait for a reference to your struct.