# Compilation error with Hyper

Tags: rust

I'm running into a compilation error I don't quite understand with a slight modification of the examples from the `master` branch of Hyper. Given the following code:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate hyper;

use futures::future::FutureResult;
use hyper::header::{ContentLength, ContentType};
use hyper::server::{Http, Service, Request, Response, Server, NewService};
use hyper::Body;
use std::fmt::Display;
use std::result;

static PHRASE: &'static [u8] = b"Hello World!";

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct MyService {}

impl Service for MyService {
    type Request = Request;
    type Response = Response;
    type Error = hyper::Error;
    type Future = FutureResult<Response, hyper::Error>;
    fn call(&self, _req: Request) -> Self::Future {
        return futures::future::ok(Response::new()
            .with_header(ContentLength(PHRASE.len() as u64))
            .with_header(ContentType::plaintext())
            .with_body(PHRASE));
    }
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct MyServer {}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct MyServeError(String);
impl<T: Display> From<T> for MyServeError {
    fn from(e: T) -> MyServeError {
        return MyServeError(format!("{}", e));
    }
}

type Result<T> = result::Result<T, MyServeError>;


impl MyServer {
    pub fn new() -> MyServer {
        return MyServer {};
    }

    fn get_server(&self) -> Result<Server<&MyServer, Body>> {
        let addr = format!("127.0.0.1:8080").parse()?;
        return Ok(Http::new().bind(&addr, self)?);
    }
}

impl NewService for MyServer {
    type Request = Request;
    type Response = Response;
    type Instance = MyService;
    type Error = hyper::Error;

    fn new_service(&self) -> std::io::Result<Self::Instance> {
        let service = MyService {};
        Ok(service)
    }
}
```

I get this compilation error:

```
 Compiling hyper-problem-demo v0.1.0 (file:///.../hyper-problem-demo)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `MyServer: std::ops::Fn<()>` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:50:31
   |
50 |         return Ok(Http::new().bind(&addr, self)?);
   |                               ^^^^ the trait `std::ops::Fn<()>` is not implemented for `MyServer`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::ops::FnOnce<()>` for `&MyServer`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `hyper::server::NewService` for `&MyServer`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `MyServer: std::ops::FnOnce<()>` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:50:31
   |
50 |         return Ok(Http::new().bind(&addr, self)?);
   |                               ^^^^ the trait `std::ops::FnOnce<()>` is not implemented for `MyServer`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `hyper::server::NewService` for `&MyServer`
```

Which I don't really understand. My intention was just to use the `MyServer` object to create new instances of `MyService` for hyper so it seems to make sense to implement `NewService`, but I don't understand why that would require an implementation of `Fn()`. `NewService` is actually implemented for `Fn() -> io::Result<Service` so maybe that's clashing somehow?

There's a full sample project [here](https://github.com/alexjg/hyper-compilation-error-demo).

Comment: Essentially the same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/40922505/155423

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have implemented `NewService` for `MyServer` however you are providing `bind` a `&MyServer` which it cannot find an implementation of `NewService` for.

The solution you go for will depend largely upon why you want to do this, but you could implement `NewService` for `&MyServer`:

```
impl<'a> NewService for &'a MyServer {
    ...
}
```